# Can the Room of Requirement conjure permanent objects?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, hogwarts

The created objects:

1.Do they vanish with time?

2.Can they be taken outside the room or do they vanish upon exiting the room?

3.Can it conjure magical items in addition to non magical ones??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Items can be removed from the room. There's no good indication that they disappear over time.

> *‘when Winky has been very drunk; he has hidden her in the Room of
> Requirement and he has found antidotes to Butterbeer there, and a nice
> elf-sized bed to settle her on while she sleeps it off, sir … and
> **Dobby knows Mr Filch has found extra cleaning materials there when he
> has run short, sir**, and –’*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix - Chapter 18: Dumbledore's Army</sup></sub>

Comment: The Room can't create food. " I went through it and met Aberforth. He’s been providing us with food, because for some reason, that’s the one thing the room doesn’t really do" -Neville in Book 6...which means that the Butterbeer antidotes weren"t really conjured by the room. They were already stored in that room. They were Real Objects, not Conjured Ones...The Room just summoned those antidotes from their place...

Comment: Also: Food is one of the 5 exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration...Butterbeer antidotes can be consumed and digested....therefore they count as food

Comment: @Mr.Riddle - You're assuming that magical potions count as food. For all you know, they count as water which we know can be summoned magically.

Comment: @Valorum- I admit that is plausible...

Comment: But that would give the Room God-like powers, wouldn't it?..You could simply keep on conjuring new objects without buying anything at all. There has to be a limiting law..

Comment: @Mr.Riddle - The room only conjures items when needed. I rather suspect that conjuring them *for sale to the public* doesn't count,

Comment: I need a Wand and I can't afford it. Will the Room permanently equip me with one??

Comment: @Mr.Riddle - Good question. All signs point to yes.